# Android Permissions Separate Class

Tags: java, android, permissions

For my application I need some permissions for using stuff like connecting to a server. I did this before by adding permissions in the manifest file as well as a Threadpolicy in the UI. Now I want to use my connecting methods in a separate class. But when I try to use the methods in this separate class, it says  the class doesn't have the 'android.permission.ACCES_NETWORK_STATE'. Therefore I tried to add the same ThreadPolicy to my separate class. But for some reason I can't use the 'setThreadPolicy method' in my separate class. Could someone find a solution?

Comment: I already found what I did wrong. I only added the 'INTERNET' permission and forgot the 'ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE' permission